# Frames and Buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, frame

Hi though i did complete the basics of java which im fairly new of, i keep getting errors when i try to add buttons on a new Frame/Panel. Care to educate me on what the problem might be?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MainClass {
    String cont_orders;
    private JFrame frame1;
    private JPanel mainpanel;
    JButton bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5;
    private JButton btotal = new JButton("Order");
    private JButton clearOr = new JButton("Clear");
    private JTextField pricetotal = new JTextField();
    private JTextField list_of_orders = new JTextField();

public MainClass(){
    gui();
}

private void gui(){
    frame1 = new JFrame("Order");
    frame1.setSize(500,430);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setResizable(false);

    mainpanel = new JPanel();
    mainpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    mainpanel.add(bt1);
        bt1 = new JButton("M-Item 1 [Soda]");  
    frame1.add(mainpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public static void main (String[]args){
    new MainClass();
}
```

}

im trying to practice on coding normally instead of relying on that automatic one in NetBeans [JFrame Form/JPanel Form]

care to help?

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace if you're getting an error, or a screenshot if you're getting a graphical issue.

One thing I see is you never set the layout of your panel - there should be a default one anyway though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The exception is - or at least thats my guess from the posted code - a NPE. Should be simple enough to solve with a debugger.

Comment: first you have to initialize the button,change to this one, 
bt1 = new JButton("M-Item 1 [Soda]");  
 mainpanel.add(bt1);
it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this cannot be done in java

```
mainpanel.add(bt1);
bt1 = new JButton("M-Item 1 [Soda]");
```

Turn it around.

Explanation: the field bt1 is at that time a variable holding the null object.
That object (value) is added, not some variable address as in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse it `bt1 = new JButton("M-Item 1 [Soda]"
mainpanel.add(bt1);`
Because if not the value of bt1 would be null so you must fill it first then use it .
Or 
`mainpanel.add(new JButton("..."));`